# NSURLRequest/NSURLConnection for tcp

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is it possible to send tcp request using NSURLRequest/NSURLConnection to an ip address and associated port from an iphone app, if yes than how?
Using NSStream it is possible to establish tcp connection to an ip and port. I am trying to establish connection to a non apple device and using nsstream it works fine but it is not very responsive [may be due to the remote device] so I am looking for NSURLRequest/NSURLResponse way of doing the same thing. Can anybody suggest how to do this [if possible]?

A little googling leads me to this link
http://lukassen.wordpress.com/2010/0...-on-iphone-os/
Is it a reason behind my problem with NSStream though I do not get any error
Thanks

Arnieterm

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

CFStream and/or NSStream are the only way to do it, eg:

http://dev.im.ethz.ch/wiki/Socket_communication_on_the_iPhone

or a wrapper around them:

http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/